# Choosing the fair winner of a Quiz using statistics

Tags: c#, sql, statistics

I'll try to remain as clear as possible and provide sufficient examples.

As there is no "correct answer" to the question of this questionnaire, how would you choose the "winner" ?

The group of people is asked to give a personal answer to the following question :

> **Order the following list** of fruits from the most important to the less important for you : 
>   - Apple
>   - Orange
>   - Pineapple
>   - Banana

The answer order is randomized. The participants can then use drag'n'drop to organize the list and build their answer before submitting it to the server that will store the order of the elements chosen by the participant.

Examples of answers :

> Mr.1's answer : 
>   - Apple
>   - Banana
>   - Orange
>   - Pineapple
>
> Mr.2's answer : 
>   - Banana
>   - Orange
>   - Apple
>   - Pineapple
>
> Mr.3's answer : 
>   - Apple
>   - Pineapple
>   - Banana
>   - Orange

The storage is done in the following SQL tables :

> Table [Choices]
>   [ID]       [Label]
>   1          Apple
>   2          Orange
>   3          Pineapple
>   4          Banana
>
> Table [Answers]
>   [ID]       [Answer]       [Points]
>   1          1;4;2;3          NULL
>   2          4;2;1;3          NULL
>   3          1;3;4;2          NULL

Of course, the real question is much more complex, and participants will have to order a list containing around 20 elements. We'll get around 100 answers, and we expect that no answer will be provided twice. Answers are stored in a MS-SQL 2012 Database.

The goal for me today, is to write the C# algorithm that will 1) select the winner and 2) give the 10 next "winners" so we can have a fallback in case there is extra stuff to give. 
It would be easy for me to select a winner if there were many similar answers, I would just select the correct answer based on the number of people having answered the same ordered list, then randomly pick someone having the "correct answer"... But we want something based on statistics, like the element mostly chosen in first, in second, in last, etc. (btw : I don't know if that's the most statistically ethic way to choose the winner in this case scenario, if you have something better to propose, please, feel free) finally giving points for an answer and being able to order the list by points...

Please submit an answer having the following code (or give a formula) :

```
private List<Answers> GetWinners(List<Answers> AllAnswers) 
{
    List<Answers> toReturn = new List<Answers>();

    //
    // Magic stuff here where [Points] are set...
    //

    // The Winner should be the first one in the returned list.        
    return toReturn.OrderByDescending(w => w.Points).Take(10).ToList();
}
```

Statistics aren't my field (I think you got that already :), please, feel free to ask any question to precise the subject.

**EDIT** : The winner is a person having submitted the vote, not the fruit ;)

Thanks !

Comment: normalize the answers table

Comment: You're right, answer's IDs should be Foreign Keys, the system will have that at the end but I tried to keep it simple because the main goal is to write the formula that will give the points so the winner.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system#Ranked_voting_methods

Comment: By coincidence, I read this yesterday; http://blog.forcerank.it/counting-votes-is-hard

Comment: "The Schulze method is somewhat more complicated than the other techniques I've described so far. It is similar to the Condorcet system in the sense that Schulze looks to see if one option dominates all other options. However, instead of directly using raw ranking data, as the Condorcet system does, the Schulze method performs a head-to-head comparison using an indirect measure of the strength between alternatives. This indirect measure is called the path strength." -- That's it ! Now I need to make it to it selects a person, not a fruit...

Comment: I've made my answer. I'll give more details later. Basically, I've use the link provided by @RJLohan and richard, digged into this side of statistics and made my own implementation of Schulze Method in C#. The system is connected to MsSQL, and allows several quiz to be run at the same time, provided a comprehensive way to read the results and some important stats like "the top 3 most important answers", "the answers we should debate", "The answers the less important", etc. I'll probably set this up on CodePlex when I'll have time. Cheers ! PS : How do I select an answer if it's a comment ? ty

Comment: @Sébastien Glad you liked that post (i wrote it)! And I hope you had fun implementing schulze. #fyi one trick I used to verify I did it right was to use the numbers on the wikipedia version of schulze as my test cases.